# How can i delete a line from text file by the line number ? And delete item from ListView by index number?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
                PopClient.Connect("mail", 110, false);
                PopClient.Authenticate("me", "me",
                    OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
                DeleteMessageByMessageId(PopClient, selectedemailindex.ToString());
            // Here i want to update the text file and the listview by deleting the line using the index number(selectedemailindex).
        }
```

The ListView control variable is lvnf.
And the text file is stored in the variable emailsIDSFile.
The index number to use to delete the line number in the text file and delete the line in the ListView by the index is stored in selectedemailindex.

Comment: What text file? And what list view? What have you tried, what is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\a.txt").ToList();
    lines.RemoveAt(linenumber); 

Listview1.Items.RemoveAt(linenumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a simple *Linq*:

```
  var lines = File
    .ReadLines("@c:\MyText.txt")
    .Where((line, index) => index != lineNumber);
```

then you may want read these lines:

```
  foreach (var line in lines) {
    ...
  }
```

write them back into a file

```
  File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyOther.txt", lines);
```

As for `ListView`, `RemoveAt` is seems that you're are looking for:

```
  MyListView.Items.RemoveAt(lineNumber);
```

P.S. your code in the question seems to be a totally *irrelevant* to the question.